# Parse string list in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, cookies

So when I retrieve a cookie in javascript I get it like this

```
"[\"name\"\054 \"name1\"\054 \"name2\"\054 \"name3\"\054 \"name4\"\054 \"name5\"]"
```

How to change it to be a list as below?

```
["name", "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const parsed = JSON.parse("[\"name\"\054 \"name1\"\054 \"name2\"\054 \"name3\"\054 \"name4\"\054 \"name5\"]");

console.log(parsed); // ["name", "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"]
```

Your cookie was stored as a JSON string, so when you retrieve it you need to use JSON to turn it back into an array (a list). Make sure it isn't null first, though:

```
if (typeof retrievedCookie == "string") {
  var myArray = JSON.parse(retrievedCookie)
} else {
  // retrievedCookie is probably null or undefined
  var myArray = []
}
```

Comment: *"JavaScript cookies are stored as JSON strings"*: that is not accurate. It happens to be the case here, but depends on what was written to the cookie. It could be JSON, it could be any other kind of formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

Just parse it like this:

```
JSON.parse(list)
```